# Symfony2 functional tests using Codeception

Tags: php, symfony, codeception

I'm trying to perform some functional tests using Codeception on my Symfony2 app.

Tests on my homepage complete successfully but if I want to perform an login operation I encounter weird errors. First let me explain how the login process works in my app.

- User fills in his credentials
- These credentials are send to another server called the MainAuth server.
- This verifies the credentials and then redirects back to the Symfony app with success or error.

When I submit the form with codeception it seems to hang at the first redirct to the MainAuth server.

In short, the login form when submitted is redirected to a URL on the MainAuth server. However the URL from the MainAuth server should redirect back to my Symfony2 app but doesn't.